# Allow fine location permission to replace fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-permissions

I want to ask user does he want to grant a permission to accces his fine location and only if he grant it I want to replace a fragment and open the locator fragment. In locator fragments there are some stores that user can see based on his location. If he doesn't allow access to fine location I want to show him proper message. This is the code:

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_locator) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                1);
        fragment = new LocatorFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentlayout, fragment);
        ft.commit();
```

Application is currently crashing because it will instantly start to replace fragment and it will crash because it replace before the user choose to approve or not approve location.

So basically i need **some loop idea or something** that will ignore user request if he choose not to allow permission and show him adequate message. And if he choose to grant then I need to replace fragment like ordinary.

Comment: Move fragment code to `onRequestPermissionsResult`..!!

Comment: I did that it's working but first time when I grant permission app close .O

Comment: You mean any error there so app close or its just your requirement to close app?

Comment: It automatically close when I grant permission and then when I start again it work like charm because it have permissions

Comment: Please check your log. there should be some error. If possible add your `logcat` here..!!

Comment: There is no error as soon as Popup dialog come out to choose to grant or deny permission background go black and when I press any of those 2 buttons app just close.. And when i restart if i chose to grant perm then everything work like it should if no it ask me again.

Comment: post your for request permission callback here.!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113929/discussion-between-spirit-and-andigeeky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below solution, hope it will work properly for you.

```
 else if (id == R.id.nav_locator) 
 {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
   if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

       goToNextFragment();

   } else {

       requestForLocationPermission(); 
   }
 }


   private void requestForLocationPermission()
   {

      if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
      {
      } 
      else {

          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
      }
   }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) 
  {
      switch (requestCode) {
       case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
           if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
           goToNextFragment();
        } 
        break;
  }
}


  public void goToNextFragment()
  {
      Fragment fragment = new LocatorFragment();
      FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      ft.replace(R.id.fragmentlayout, fragment);
      ft.commit();
  }
```