# Connect .net Webservice with Android

Tags: android, android-ksoap2, networkonmainthread

**Webservice class code** :

```
public class WebService {

    String namespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";
    private String url = "http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertWeight.asmx";

    String SOAP_ACTION;
    SoapObject request = null, objMessages = null;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
    AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport;

    WebService() {
    }
    protected void SetEnvelope() {

        try {

            // Creating SOAP envelope
            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            //You can comment that line if your web service is not .NET one.
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(url);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Soap Exception---->>>" + e.toString());
        }
    }

    // MethodName variable is define for which webservice function  will call
    public String getConvertedWeight(String MethodName, String weight,
                                     String fromUnit, String toUnit)
    {

        try {
            SOAP_ACTION = namespace + MethodName;

            //Adding values to request object
            request = new SoapObject(namespace, MethodName);

            //Adding Double value to request object
            PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
            weightProp.setName("Weight");
            weightProp.setValue(weight);
            weightProp.setType(double.class);
            request.addProperty(weightProp);

            //Adding String value to request object
            request.addProperty("FromUnit", "" + fromUnit);
            request.addProperty("ToUnit", "" + toUnit);

            SetEnvelope();

            try {

                //SOAP calling webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                //Got Webservice response
                String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();

                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                return e.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

**My updated Activity code :**

```
public class CheckDNLoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button webserviceCallButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.webservice);
        final TextView webserviceResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.webserviceResponse);

        webserviceCallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                webserviceResponse.setText("Requesting to server .....");

                new ExecuteService().execute();

             }
         });
     }


     class ExecuteService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                //Create Webservice class object
                WebService com = new WebService();

                // Initialize variables
                String weight   = "18000";
                String fromUnit = "Grams";
                String toUnit   = "Kilograms";

                //Call Webservice class method and pass values and get response
                String aResponse = com.getConvertedWeight("ConvertWeight", weight, fromUnit, toUnit);

                //Alert message to show webservice response
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), weight+" Gram= "+aResponse+" Kilograms",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.i("AndroidExampleOutput", "----"+aResponse);
                return aResponse;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                webserviceResponse.setText("Response : "+ result);

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}
        }
}
```

This is my updated  logcat . When i run my application i got an **error:**,

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.example.dell.piechart2, PID: 2762
      java.lang.NullPointerException
          at com.example.dell.piechart2.CheckDNLoginActivity$ExecuteService.onPostExecute(CheckDNLoginActivity.java:63)
          at com.example.dell.piechart2.CheckDNLoginActivity$ExecuteService.onPostExecute(CheckDNLoginActivity.java:38)
          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
          at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
          at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is the problem? Please help me. I post my full logcat here. you can also check it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means dont do expensive task on the Main thread like network operations.

Comment: plzzz help me guys...i m trying it from 3 to 4 days. but i m not getting the result. someone plzz help me

Comment: can u plzz elaborate ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Async Task class as below,

**First change your button click event by below**

```
  webserviceCallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            webserviceResponse.setText("Requesting to server .....");

            new ExecuteService().execute();

        }
    });
```

**Now, check below your entire activity code**

```
    public class CheckDNLoginActivity extends Activity {

        Button webserviceCallButton;
        TextView webserviceResponse;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            webserviceCallButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.webservice);
            webserviceResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.webserviceResponse);

            webserviceCallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    webserviceResponse.setText("Requesting to server .....");

                    new ExecuteService().execute();

                 }
             });
         }


     class ExecuteService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                //Create Webservice class object
                WebService com = new WebService();

                // Initialize variables
                String weight   = "18000";
                String fromUnit = "Grams";
                String toUnit   = "Kilograms";

                //Call Webservice class method and pass values and get response
                String aResponse = com.getConvertedWeight("ConvertWeight", weight, fromUnit, toUnit);

                //Alert message to show webservice response
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), weight+" Gram= "+aResponse+" Kilograms",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.i("AndroidExampleOutput", "----"+aResponse);
                return aResponse;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                webserviceResponse.setText("Response : "+ result);

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}
        }
}
```

Comment: error in ExecuteService class..it can not be recognize this method

Comment: @ashisharma where you have put ExecuteService class ? , It should be inside CheckDNLoginActivity class check it

Comment: i paste ur code inside the tOnClickListener and then no error in code.

Comment: but when i run it shows..requesting to server and then stop.

Comment: unfortunately stop

Comment: Make sure you have set permission for Internet in manifest file and if you are using marshmellow then runtime permission required

Comment: If you still get error then show me your latest code with changes as per my suggestion

Comment: error in doinbackground method..java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: i m using marshmellow

Comment: For marshmellow you need to set runtime permission for that check my this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37659455/2741598

Comment: where should i use this runtime code ?? In java code or somehwere else ? and which part of code i used for runtime permissions ?

Comment: see i have change your code, you have made big mistake, class should be out side of oncreate method you have declare it inside on click method now use above updated code

Comment: currently if possible then first check in other emulator or device below marshmellow, in lollipop or kitkat or jellybean whatever

Comment: i used your code but then it is not get the ExecuteService method. Thats why i keep it in onclick.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Just do one thing and I hope it will resolve your issue, make comment on toast or remove that line

Comment: it could not find some class or method.

Comment: means which class ?

Comment: i comment toast then java.lang.NullPointerException this error occured

Comment: If you know debugging then debug app and check at which sentence you get this exception and what is null in your code

Comment: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle'Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateLis..Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController'...Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar'

Comment: this type of classe and method not find

Comment: are you able do run it in your system ?

Comment: Above you mentioned are not your errors, so may be by mistake you have placed some code at unspecific place therefore this issue happened you need to check it

Comment: -java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to www.webservicex.net/173.201.44.188 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
This message is show on my logcat..when i run it

Comment: I am not getting your exception details but still you have put wrong code, still you have placed async task class inside button click

Comment: check internet connection in your device in which you run app, may be slow internet or not connected as time out is showing only when internet is not available it is not code problem

Comment: i posted my logcat here.I hope it will help u to find a solution

Comment: i run my app on emulator

Comment: Dear it again toast message error so please don't forget to comment or remove that toast line

Comment: i commented it. but nothing changed.

Comment: If there is any issue then it should change the exception message

Comment: now check are you getting response in  Log.i("AndroidExampleOutput", "----"+aResponse); ?

Comment: how can i check it?

Comment: just check my edited answer it will help you, and this time pls comment toast or remove it

Comment: it return success

Comment: Now i got a new error....java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to www.webservicex.net/173.201.44.188 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Comment: As i told you earlier it is problem of internet as it is not issue from code side so check your internet connection

Comment: hey output is response : 18

Comment: yeah sure...thnx once again

Comment: Can I contact you in any other way

Comment: I don't have any idea about highchart, but I recommend you to use this one as it is better and flexible in all way to use: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: I made through this. I m trying to make pie charts through highcharts.

Comment: Is  it a error of netwrk?? 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/AuthenticateUser.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@9d140588

Comment: SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@9d181820
When i gave running url it gives the same error

Comment: plzzz rply @Vickyexpert

Comment: can u help me in following link....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263263/i-am-trying-to-connect-net-web-service-with-android

Comment: It should be problem with your API link which you have mentioned in url so check it

Comment: I have solved this error. But some other problem is occur. Can u plzz click on link in my last comment and check.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286876/net-web-service-calling#comment65911591_39286876

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

You can use an `AsyncTask` to do network operations.

This is the `AsyncTask` code,

```
private class MyNetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        webserviceResponse.setText("Requesting to server .....");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //Create Webservice class object
        WebService com = new WebService();

        // Initialize variables
        String weight   = params[1];
        String fromUnit = params[2];
        String toUnit   = params[3];

        //Call Webservice class method and pass values and get response
        return com.getConvertedWeight(params[0], weight, fromUnit, toUnit);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aResponse) {
        webserviceResponse.setText("Response : "+aResponse);
    }
}
```

This is how you call the `AyncTask`,

```
webserviceCallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        new MyNetworkTask().execute("ConvertWeight", "18000", "Grams", "Kilograms");

    }

});
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) SO thread for more info.

Comment: error in MyNetworkTask() class..this is not calling this method. cant resolve symbol

Comment: error in doinbackground method..java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: yes i used updated code.and when i run it then this error occured

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public class request extends AppCompatActivity {
 TextView webserviceResponse;

String aResponse="nul";

String f_name="";

WebserviceCall com = new WebserviceCall();

Button webserviceCallButton;

@Override

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.request);

     webserviceCallButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     webserviceResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    webserviceCallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            f_name   = "1";

            new LongOperation().execute("");


        }
    });

}
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        //Create Webservice class object

        // Initialize variables

        //Call Webservice class method and pass values and get response
        aResponse = com.getchange_liveserver("wb", f_name);

        //Alert message to show webservice response

        Log.i("AndroidExampleOutput", "----"+aResponse);

      //  webserviceResponse.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);
        // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed

        // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        webserviceResponse.setText("Response : "+aResponse);


    }









 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {               
  webserviceResponse.setText("Requesting to server .....");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

}