# Android M 6.0: cannot remove accounts : java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, accountmanager, securityexception, android-securityexception

On Marshmallow, i fell on this Exception when I add a google account type:

> " java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10121 cannot remove accounts of
>   type: com.google at "

I add the accound using

```
mAccountManager.addAccount("com.google", null, null, null, activity.this, null, null);
```

And sometime i need to delete all accounts using

`mAccountManager.removeAccount(account, this, null, null);`

the app has Admin role, and all permissions is think about:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

i asked the user for :

```
Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

How to delete account managed by google authenticator ...? 
all is working well on Lollipop, of course

thanks !

Comment: For Marshmellow you need runtime permission check my below answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37659455/2741598

Comment: i made the runtime permisssion : Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS